# Kubernetes ingress controller Traefik routing not working properly

Tags: kubernetes, routes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik, traefik-ingress

I'm unable to configure [Traefik ingress](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/providers/kubernetes-ingress/) to work as intened.

I am suppose to see 3 different services running on paths `/`, `/api-server`, and `/hermes`. But for whatever reason I'm only seeing one application (theia-svc) in all paths.

**k8.ingress-traefik.yml:**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    # traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
    # traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: "PathPrefixStrip"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: "/"
    # traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/frontend-entry-points: "http,https"

  name: traefik-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: traefik
  rules:
    - host: dev.mywebsite.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: theia-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
          - path: /api-server
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: api-server-svc
                port:
                  number: 8082
          - path: /hermes
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: hermes-svc
                port:
                  number: 8000
          - path: /hermes2/
            pathType: Exact
            backend:
              service:
                name: hermes-svc
                port:
                  number: 8000
          - path: /hermes3/
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: hermes-svc
                port:
                  number: 8000
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - dev.mywebsite.io
      secretName: tls-secret
```

**`kubectl get service` to grab IPs to test**:

```bash
NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)          AGE     SELECTOR
api-server-svc   LoadBalancer   10.104.36.20    23.29.118.63   8082:32017/TCP   137m    app=api-server-pod
hermes-svc       ClusterIP      10.106.25.215   <none>         8000/TCP         67m     app=hermes-pod
kubernetes       ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>         443/TCP          5h36m   <none>
theia-svc        ClusterIP      10.96.41.226    <none>         80/TCP           5h7m    app=theia-pod
```

**`curl 10.106.25.215:8000` to test *hermes-svc***:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>...</html>
```

**Results in the browser:**

```
- https://dev.mywebsite.io/api-server    => 404
- https://dev.mywebsite.io/              => theia-svc
- https://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes        => theia-svc
- https://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes/       => theia-svc
- https://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes2       => theia-svc
- https://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes2/      => 404
- https://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes3       => theia-svc
- https://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes3/      => 404
```

---

## EDIT: 07/03/2023

I found out that I was reading wrong documentation thus using incorrect manifest syntax. I was able to fix the routing issue but now I'm not seeing TLS (https) cert being applied, which it did with previous manifests with broken routing.

The new **k8.ingress-traefik.yml**:

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingressroute
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
    - match: Host(`dev.mywebsite.io`) && PathPrefix(`/api-server`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: api-server-svc
          port: 8082
      middlewares:
        - name: stripprefix
    - match: Host(`dev.mywebsite.io`) && PathPrefix(`/hermes`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: hermes-svc
          port: 8000
      middlewares:
        - name: stripprefix
  tls:
    certResolver: myresolver
    options:
      name: traefik-tls-option
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: stripprefix
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    prefixes:
      - /api-server
      - /hermes
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: TLSOption
metadata:
  name: traefik-tls-option
spec:
  minVersion: VersionTLS12
  cipherSuites:
    - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    - TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    - TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
  curvePreferences:
    - CurveP521
    - CurveP384
  sniStrict: true
```

Comment: What happens if you put the rule for `/` at the end of the list of `paths` instead of the beginning?

Comment: @larsks I get this error `* spec.rules[0].http.paths[5].path: Invalid value: "hermes4/": must be an absolute path`.

Comment: (a) The error is accurate; your paths must start with a `/` and `hermes4/` does not, and (b) there is no `hermes4` in the example config you've posted in this question.

Comment: @larsks Oh you meant put the index path route at the very end. Yeah I already tried that which had me no luck.

Answer (score -1):

There are several issues with your ingress resource.

First, as I noted in my comment, rules are processed *in order*. If your first rule is a prefix rule that matches `/`, then it's going to match **everything**; the other rules don't matter.

Next, you're using `Exact` rules for the first two `/hermes*` paths, but you're not being consistent in your use of trailing slashes.  You have:

- `/hermes`
- `/hermes2/`
- `/hermes3/`

Note the inconsistent use of the trailing `/`. That means:

1. A request for `/hermes` will match the rule for `/hermes`.
2. A request for `/hermes/` won't match anything.
3. A request for `/hermes2` won't match anything.
4. A request for `/hermes2/` will match the rule for `/hermes2/`.
5. A request for `/hermes3` won't match anything.
6. A request for `/hermes3/` will match the rule for `/hermes3/`.
7. A request for `/hermes3/foo` will match the rule for `/hermes3/`.

If you're expecting both `/hermes` and `/hermes/` to go to the same place...well, welcome to [Traefik issue #5159](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/issues/5159) (and also #563, #4521, #3330, #4804, #3852, #1037, etc).

Depending on your requirements, the simplest solution may be to replace your `Exact` rules with `Prefix` rules. If we write instead (I've removed the SSL config because it's not relevant for these tests):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: traefik
  rules:
    - host: dev.mywebsite.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api-server
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: api-server-svc
                port:
                  number: 8082
          - path: /hermes
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: hermes-svc
                port:
                  number: 8000
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: theia-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Then we get:

```
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/api-server       => api
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/                 => theia
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes           => hermes
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes/          => hermes
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes2          => hermes
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes2/         => hermes
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes3          => hermes
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes3/         => hermes
```

Of course, that also means we get:

```
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes113        => hermes
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes_was_dog   => hermes
```

Etc.

---

Alternately, you can solve the trailing slash issue by introducing some regular expression middleware. Given these manifests:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: example-add-trailing-slash@kubernetescrd
  labels:
    app: traefik-example
  name: traefik-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: traefik
  rules:
  - host: dev.mywebsite.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: api-server-svc
            port:
              number: 8082
        path: /api-server
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: hermes-svc
            port:
              number: 8000
        path: /hermes/
        pathType: Exact
      - backend:
          service:
            name: hermes-svc
            port:
              number: 8000
        path: /hermes2/
        pathType: Exact
      - backend:
          service:
            name: hermes-svc
            port:
              number: 8000
        path: /hermes3/
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: theia-svc
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix

---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  labels:
    app: traefik-example
  name: add-trailing-slash
spec:
  redirectRegex:
    permanent: true
    regex: ^https?://(.*)/(hermes[23]?)$
    replacement: /${2}/
```

We get the following behavior:

```
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/api-server       => api
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/                 => theia
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes           => hermes
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes/          => hermes
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes/foo       => theia
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes2          => hermes
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes2/         => hermes
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes2/foo      => theia
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes3          => hermes
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes3/         => hermes
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes3/foo      => hermes
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes113        => theia
- http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes_was_a_dog => theia
```

**NB**: Note that when referencing a Middleware, Traefik requires that you prepend the Namespace in which your Ingress is deployed; I'm deploying the above manifests into a Namespace named `example`, hence the `add-trailing-slash` Middleware is referenced as `example-add-trailing-slash`.

In the above examples, note that `/hermes` and `/hermes/` both go to `hermes-svc`, but `/hermes/foo` does **not** because you're using an `Exact` path rule (and similarly for `/hermes2`).

This isn't true for `/hermes3/foo` because in that rule you're using a **Prefix** match.

I've put together a complete example [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-76576995-traefik-paths).

---

For handling your most recent comment, I've assumed that we should be matching everything as a `Prefix`, rather than using `Exact`, so that:

- `http://dev.mywebsite.io/api-server/a/b/c` goes to `api-server` with path `/a/b/c`
- `http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes/a/b/c` goes to `hermes` with path `/a/b/c`
- `http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes2/a/b/c` goes to `hermes` with path `/a/b/c`
- `http://dev.mywebsite.io/hermes3/a/b/c` goes to `hermes` with path `/a/b/c`

For those results, we add a [`stripPrefix` middleware](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/stripprefix/), like this:

```
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: strip-prefix
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    forceSlash: false
    prefixes:
      - /api-server
      - /hermes2
      - /hermes3
      - /hermes
```

And write our Ingress like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: example-add-trailing-slash@kubernetescrd,example-strip-prefix@kubernetescrd
spec:
  ingressClassName: traefik
  rules:
    - host: dev.mywebsite.io
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api-server
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: api-server-svc
                port:
                  number: 8082
          - path: /hermes
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: hermes-svc
                port:
                  number: 8000
          - path: /hermes2
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: hermes-svc
                port:
                  number: 8000
          - path: /hermes3
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: hermes-svc
                port:
                  number: 8000
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: theia-svc
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Note that we're using both the `add-trailing-slash` and `strip-prefix` middlewares in this example.

I've updated [the linked repository](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-76576995-traefik-paths) and the included tests.

Comment: I tried changing the order as you mentioned but that still didn't work for me. For some reason, only the '/' path seems to work for all services. I don't know why it's not picking up any sub paths. So even if I have just one path (e.g. `/hermes`) in the config, it won't work unless it's set to `/`. Is this related to Traefik bug?

Comment: I tested the configuration I show here, using Traefik installed from the [official helm cart](https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart), version 23.1.0. If you try deploying *exactly* the manifests presented in this answer, do you see different behavior?

Comment: Yes, I just copied and pasted your answer and it's giving me the same result. This issue has been happening to me in both traditional Kubernetes setup or K3S. Do you see working sub-paths from your end?

Comment: Yes, the prefixes match as expected (see e.g. the example for `hermes3/foo`).

Comment: I found out that the actual problem is that `PathPrefixStrip` is not working properly ([doc](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/basics/#path-matcher-usage-guidelines)). For example, when I send request to **/hermes/hello**, the app should receive request as **/hello**, not as **/hermes/hello**. I also tried this in nginx-ingress which had same behavior. Do you happen to know how I can solve this?

Comment: I am not using `PathPrefixStrip` anywhere in my example, so that means that you didn't copy and paste my answer and get the same result. I'll see about addressing the prefix stripping issue later this evening.

Comment: I did copy & paste at one point which didn't work thus, I was continuously debugging `PathPrefixStrip` as that was suppose to be the fix. However, I just found out that I'm reading incorrect documentation. I was able to fix the issue with `IngressRoute` + `Middleware` but now I'm not seeing TLS (https) cert being applied :(. I'll update my post with my new manifests and if you know what I can do to fix TLS, please let me know.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show one way of using the `stripPrefix` middleware.

Comment: If you let me know what the -1 was for I can try to fix it!